# Item doesn't get deleted after launching .splice function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make an app in which I add and delete items from a `Flatlist`, I use React Native and when I add the item everything goes fine, but when I want to delete it and execute the functions nothing happens, I used a console.log to see the state `workoutList` which is the state I am using in the Flatlist, but in the Terminal it reloads the same array again. I use `onLongPress` to launch the `Alert` to confirm the erase of the item and thhrough that launch the function that deletes the item, which is `removeItem`. This is an example of the Array I'm using:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "Friday": false,
    "Monday": true,
    "Saturday": false,
    "Sunday": false,
    "Thursday": false,
    "Tuesday": false,
    "Wednesday": false,
    "key": 0.4736452015308592,
    "workoutName": "",
  },
]
```

this the code:

```
export class Workout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      workoutList: [],
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.route.params?.workout) {
      return {
        workoutList: [...state.workoutList, props.route.params.workout],
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

   openTwoButtonAlert = (index) => {
    Alert.alert(
       'Delete Workout',
      'Are you sure to delete this Workout?',
      [
        {text: 'Delete', onPress: ()=>this.removeItem(index)},

        {text: 'Cancel', 
           style: 'cancel',
           
        },
      ],
    );
  }

  removeItem(index){
    const newData = [...this.state.workoutList];
    newData.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({workoutList: newData}); 
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.workoutList)
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            Your Current Workouts
          </Text>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.workoutList}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
              renderItem={({ index, item}) => (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("WorkoutCreated", {
                    workoutName: item.workoutName,
                    Monday: item.Monday,
                    Tuesday: item.Tuesday,
                    Wednesday: item.Wednesday,
                    Thursday: item.Thursday,
                    Friday: item.Friday,
                    Saturday: item.Saturday,
                    Sunday: item.Sunday,
                  })} 
                  onLongPress={()=>this.openTwoButtonAlert(index)}>
                    <Text>{item.workoutName}</Text>       
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

**Other Screen**

```
submitWorkout = (
    workoutName,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
  ) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Workout", {
      workout: {
        key: Math.random(),
        workoutName: workoutName,
        Monday: Monday,
        Tuesday: Tuesday,
        Wednesday: Wednesday,
        Thursday: Thursday,
        Friday: Friday,
        Saturday: Saturday,
        Sunday: Sunday,
      },
    });
  };

<Button
   onPress={() => {
              this.submitWorkout(
                this.state.workoutName,
                this.state.Monday,
                this.state.Tuesday,
                this.state.Thursday,
                this.state.Wednesday,
                this.state.Thursday,
                this.state.Friday,
                this.state.Saturday,
                this.state.Sunday
              );
            }}
/>
```

Comment: Just a side note on accessibility/usability: as you are setting the confirmation button text yourself, may I suggest you use something less prone to generate confusion or misunderstandings? "Delete" and "Cancel" are basically synonyms; if the question is "*Are you sure you want to delete... ?*" the options should be "*Yes*" and "*No*" or, even better, "*Yes, delete it*" and "*No, keep it*".

Answer (score 1):

You should use `filter` to remove item.

```
removeItem = (index) => {
  this.setState({
    workoutList: this.state.workoutList.filter((item, i) => i !== index),
  });
}
```

Comment: Even after doing this change, I get the same result, nothing changes and in the Terminal it returns again the same array.

Comment: Did you try to add bind in the constructor: `this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);

Comment: I tried your code and I still get the same result, I also tried `this.removeItem.bind(this)` and even by doing both it doesn't work, this thing is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with the below code.

like.

```
class Workout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      workoutList: props.route.params?.workout ? props.route.params.workout : [],
    };
  }

  openTwoButtonAlert = (index) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Delete Workout',
      'Are you sure to delete this Workout?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          onPress:() => this.removeItem(index)
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel', 
          style: 'cancel',
        },
      ],
    );
  }

  removeItem(index){
    const newData = [...this.state.workoutList];
    const updatedData = newData.filter((_obj, ind) => ind !== index)
    this.setState({workoutList: [...updatedData]}); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>
          Your Current Workouts
        </Text>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.workoutList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
          renderItem={({ index, item}) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("WorkoutCreated", {
                      workoutName: item.workoutName,
                      Monday: item.Monday,
                      Tuesday: item.Tuesday,
                      Wednesday: item.Wednesday,
                      Thursday: item.Thursday,
                      Friday: item.Friday,
                      Saturday: item.Saturday,
                      Sunday: item.Sunday,
                    })
                  }
                } 
                onLongPress={()=>this.openTwoButtonAlert(index)}>
                  <Text>{item.workoutName}</Text>       
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )
          }}
        />
          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default Workout;
```

Comment: I tired your solution, but I still get the same result.

Comment: @Salvo, I have updated the code please have a try with it.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I create the Array in another screen and I use React Navigation and `getDerivedStateFromProps` to get that array and insert it in the state `workoutList`

Comment: I had tried and working perfect and i removed the getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: as it called everytime after the update occues

Comment: I forgot to delete getDerivedStateFromProps, by copying your exact code I can't see anything in the Flatlist by it shows in the Terminal

Comment: Maybe it's the way I send the params, I updated the code above so you can see hwo I send the params from the other screen

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the updated state in your console log try to add a callback function in your setState and then add the console log.

Eg:

```
removeItem = (index) => {
  this.setState({
    workoutList: this.state.workoutList.filter((item, i) => i !== index),
  },()=>{console.log("Workout: ", this.state.workoutList)});
}
```